# What is the Latin term for forward from a page?

Tags: terminology, latin

In English scholarly references there is an expression meaning *from this page forward*, but I can't remember what it is.

Comment: I’ve always used ff.

Comment: See [this Wictionary page for an explanation of ff.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ff.), suggested by Xanne. Wictionary says that the short form "ff." refers to the Latin word _folio_.

Answer (score 1):

The Latin term you are looking for is ***et sequentes***, or ***et sequentia*** which is abbreviated as

> ***et seq.*** (et sequens), ***et seqq.*** or ***et sequa.***: "and the words, pages, etc. that follow" (use et seqq. or et sequa. if "the following"
> is plural).

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_abbreviations) explains

> It is used when referring the reader to a passage beginning in a certain
> place, and continuing, e.g. "p.6 et seqq." means "page 6 and the pages
> that follow".

This law oriented [site called Jrank](https://law.jrank.org/pages/6589/Et-Seq.html#:%7E:text=An%20abbreviation%20for%20the%20Latin,meaning%20%22and%20the%20following.%22) shows that this phrase is not only used for pages:

> The phrase et seq. is used in references made to *particular pages or
> sections of cases, articles, regulations, or statutes* to indicate that
> the desired information is continued on the pages or in the sections
> following a designated page or section, as "***p. 238 et seq.***" or
> "***section 43 et seq.***"